# Can I pass a HWND in a COM method?

Tags: windows, com, hwnd

Is it possible to have a COM method which passes a `HWND`? With the following method in my object `CoCreateInstance` returns `DISP_E_BADVARTYPE` (`0x80020008`):

```
STDMETHODIMP ShowDialog(HWND hWndParent);
```

So far, I'm getting round this problem by passing an `OLE_HANDLE` then casting it but it feels like a cludge:

```
STDMETHODIMP ShowDialog(OLE_HANDLE hWndParent);
```

Comment: Note that this can happen if you have a property on the interface with HWND type, even if it's never referenced in the .NET code!  I spent quite some time chasing my tail trying to run a similar problem down before I noticed that there was something else on the interface (which I wasn't using) with an `[out, retval] HWND *` argument.  The interface was `oleautomation` but not `dual`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that HWND is a pointer to a struct thats why you can't use it in the IDL.
If you look at Microsoft Typelibs you will see all sort of variation on how to pass a handle (From int to long to HANDLE).

Answer (score 1):

Your interface is probably registered as "dual", and HWND is not one of the types supported by OLE automation. Does your interface need to be IDispatch-compatible (do you need to call it from scripting or late-bound languages)?  If not, deriving from IUnknown rather than IDispatch and not registering as dual will help you out.

NB: Casting is okay as long as you are only using the method in-process.

Comment: In my experience, this error can still happen with an interface that is not marked as `dual`.